# how to convert any image file into EPS format in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd, imagick

I have an image processing system in PHP with Imagemagick. The existing system will be processing images of EPS format for some process and PNGs for the remaining process. So, I need to upload the same image file in EPS and PNG. I am doing the file upload facility now, which should automate the procedure of converting any format image file into EPS and PNG and should save in corresponding locations.

What I need now is to be able to convert any image format file into EPS and PNG, so then I can process and save them, but there are some DPI limitations. So I need to save the files into these EPS and PNG formats so that only the existing system can use those files properly.

Please advice me if there is any way to convert image files into EPS and PNG with PHP and Imagemagick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any image to eps format by following code

```
public function convertImageToEps(){
    $imgUrl = WWW_ROOT.'imfcs.jpg';
    $imagic = new Imagick();
    $imagic->readImage($imgUrl);
    $imagic->setImageFormat('eps');
    $imagic->writeImage(WWW_ROOT.'simfcs.eps');
    return true ;
}
```

Comment: Imagemagick will convert raster images into EPS by enclosing the raster image in a vector EPS shell. So the result will be as large as the raster input and will not be a vector image. Imagemagick does not vectorize raster images.